# How can I simplify my url with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I would like this:

```
http://www.website.com/test/view
```

to actually call this:

```
http://www.website.com/index.php/test/view
```

I tried an .htaccess file that looks like this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Well, it seems that all the answers (including my own) are correct. The problem was that git was not updating my .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set "RewriteEngine On" At The first line??

I used this once and it worked fine for me:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z\-]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Yes, that is my first line. I edited my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^ index.php%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```